# Pass request parameters to jsf method in xhtml file?

Tags: jsf-2, el

i use el-impl-2.2.jar with jsf 2 that allows to call a method from managed bean in xhtml file and pass it params.

if i test this :

```
#{myBean.findById(1)}
```

all works fine. but now i want to retrieve params from request 
i have tried this

```
#{myBean.findById(${param.id})}
```

it's not working. 
any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression `#{myBean.findById(param.id)}` should work. You shouldn't search in your view. You should do it in controller. Create `ManagedBean` and do it there.

Read mkyong article http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/.

Comment: i know i search form my bean, i just call method findById in my bean that call ejb3 to retrieve data in database and return it to view.